# Cannot setup cluster of ElasticSearch with Docker of 2 machines on 3 nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

Im trying to setup Elasticsearch 3 nodes on 2 EC2 machines as the following configuration with docker compose.

following the doc -
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

(run this script on each machine)

```
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - network.publish_host=10.2.0.38
      - cluster.name=my-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - vit01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - network.publish_host=10.2.0.38
      - cluster.name=my-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - vit02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - network.publish_host=10.2.0.243
      - cluster.name=my-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - vit03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  vit01:
    external: true
  vit02:
    external: true
  vit03:
    external: true

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

The error I got on both machines

```
es01    | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [es02][10.2.0.38:9300] connect_exception",
es01    | "at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$ChannelsConnectedListener.onFailure(TcpTransport.java:978) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
es01    | "at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.lambda$toBiConsumer$2(ActionListener.java:198) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
es01    | "at org.elasticsearch.common.concurrent.CompletableContext.lambda$addListener$0(CompletableContext.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-core-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
es01    | "at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2152) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at org.elasticsearch.common.concurrent.CompletableContext.completeExceptionally(CompletableContext.java:57) ~[elasticsearch-core-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
es01    | "at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4TcpChannel.lambda$addListener$0(Netty4TcpChannel.java:68) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:615) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:578) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[?:?]",
es01    | "at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]",
es01    | "Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: 10.2.0.38/10.2.0.38:9300",
```

TCP port 9300 is opened on both machines I can enter from by:
telnet 10.2.0.243 9300 and vice versa.
Security groups are ok.

What I'm missing ?

Comment: I can see you've raised this on https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-setup-cluster-of-es-with-docker-of-2-ec2-machines-on-3-nodes/286890 as well, and I think that answers what you need?

Comment: No, maybe it is not supported by docker compose? Only with swarm?

Comment: docker compose cannot run containers on multiple hosts with the one file, no